# Created a symbolic link to /usr/bin/clang++-5.0, but the link only compiles C files

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang

Ubuntu 16.04, no GCC. Installed clang: 
`sudo apt install clang-5.0`

Created two links:

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang-5.0 clang
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang++-5.0 cclang`

Compile a simple C file, helloworld.c. Either clang or cclang works fine.

Try to compile a C++ file:   `cclang helloworld.cpp`

Got errors. Same error messages as `clang helloworld.cpp` (C compiler to compile a C++ file)

However, `/usr/bin/clang++-5.0 helloworld.cpp` works fine.

Anything wrong in my symbolic link creation?

Comment: You cannot create symbolic links to clang++, they won't work. (clang++ is itself a symbolic link to clang, this might hint you of what the problem is)

Comment: Yes. clang++-5.0 is a symbolic link. `cclang -> /usr/bin/clang++-5.0*` and     `clang++-5.0 -> ../lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang++`.  On the other side, the created link `clang` also points to another symbolic link:  `clang -> /usr/bin/clang-5.0*`, and `clang-5.0 -> ../lib/llvm-5.0/bin/clang*'.  `clang` works fine on C files, but `cclang` doesn't.

Comment: So the name of the symbolic link that starts the compiler is significant in determining its behaviour, wouldn't you agree?

Comment: Why the link's name is important? My understanding is the name of a symbolic link won't affect the function. The file it points to does the job.

Comment: Are you asking how it is done technically? The name of the link is argv[0] passed to the program, so the program can choose to behave differently depending on the name it was started under.

Comment: Thank you. I noticed clang++, clang-cl, and clang-cpp in /usr/lib/llvm-5.0/bin/ are all linked to clang and they behave differently, but still don't understand why the different link names cause different behaviors. What is the actual command or function call when the link name is passed to the program as arg[0]?

Comment: `if (strcmp(...)) {...}` perhaps?